# Maximum value of probability distribution

Tags: distributions, notation, extreme-value

```
G(x_t)
```

returns probability distribution for n entries at t,
and I want to represent the time at which the maximum value among those probabilities is the highest.

Thus, if we have (0.1,0.2,0.7) at t=0 and (0.1,0.1,0.8) at t=1, then the answer should be 1.

I'm thinking of following notation:

```
arg max_i max G(x_i)
```

But I'm not sure whether max() can be used here to denote the highest probability among the probabilities in the distribution.
Can it?

Comment: When you say *I'm not sure whether max() can be used...*, is the question about notation, definitions, programming or what?

Comment: @RichardHardy sorry I meant notation